# Using an AJAX success function to prepend content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using JQuery and AJAX to submit and process a form. I would like to prepend content from the processing form (AJAX url:comment.php). How can I do this? I know I will have to use Success: function().

My AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "comment.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function () {
        //code to prepend the content from comment.php
    }
});
```

My Comment.php File:

```
//Some processing code

<p> Success!! </p>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just prepend whatever the PHP script returns :

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "comment.php",  
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#elementID').prepend(data); // prepends "hello kitty"
    }
});
```

Comment.php

```
<?php
    // process form or whatever
    echo "hello kitty";
?>
```

note that any output from the PHP file will be returned to $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method to prepend html content to an element

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "comment.php",  
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        //code to prepend the content from comment.php
        $('#myelement').prepend(html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in Comment.php File:

```
<?php echo "<p> Success!! </p>"; ?>
```

make following changes in your ajax function:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "comment.php",  
    data: dataString,
    success: function(resp) {
        $("#msg").prepend(resp);
    }
});
```

put following div code where you want to display message.

```
<div id="msg"></div>
```